# Include a line feed in a powershell script argument

Tags: powershell, linefeed

I am using a .bat file to invoke a powershell script.

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\PushOverPS.ps1 "Line1\nLine2"
```

I want my pushover message to be multiline, and the above just has a single line with the \n in it. The Pushover support people said I should try including a line feed rather than the \n. How would I do that?

Here is the powershell script:

```
$uri = "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json"
$parameters = @{
  token = "removed"
  user = "removed"
  message = $args[0]
}
$parameters | Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post
```

My .bat file is passing an argument (string) to the PS script. So far, adding \n or ` in the string being passed does not result in a multiline message.

Comment: No idea, but I suspect it'd be easier to refactor your `PushOverPS.ps1` script to accept multiple arguments instead of a single multi-line string...

Comment: You could try a backtick instead of a backslash - ```Line1`nLine2```. That’s the normal escape sequence for a line feed in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

use the back tick before the new line feed for powershell,

```
`n
```

Answer (score 0):

With input still as "Line1\nLine2", make this one line change:

```
message = $args[0] -replace "\\n","`n"
```

Test code:

```
$uri = "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json"
$parameters = @{
  token = "removed"
  user = "removed"
  message = $args[0] -replace "\\n","`n"
}
write-host $parameters.message
```

But not sure if `n will pass correctly into post. Maybe replace `n with url encode version: %0A.

EDIT: updated code so output message parameter is in quotes, which may be required by the target web api to support newlines in the parameters. OP has confirmed this works.

```
$uri = "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json"
$parameters = @{
  token = "removed"
  user = "removed"
  message = "`"" + $($args[0] -replace "\\n","`n") + "`""
}
write-host $parameters.message
```

Comment: I can replace \n with %0A, but then I just get this: Line1%0ALine2. Nothing else worked either.

Comment: I meant to replace \`n with %0A in the powershell. Your batch script input should still use \n. How are you checking your output? Is it through api.pushover.net? Perhaps the problem is that we are not using the correct newline character that api.pushover.net accepts. Looking at https://pushover.net/api, I don't see any mention of support for newline, even in the html styling section (eg: <br>). Try replacing \`n with <br> in the powershell?

Comment: Did you try the test code above where \n is replaced with \`n in powershell? According to this https://support.pushover.net/i35-sending-multi-line-notifications-through-the-api, sending the actual newline character to the api works. Maybe the message needs quotes around it? message = "\`"" + $($args[0] -replace "\\n","<br>") + "\`""

Comment: I meant to use \`n instead of <br>: message = "\`"" + $($args[0] -replace "\\n","\`n") + "\`""

So output is:
line1: `"Line1`
line2: `Line2"`

Comment: Using this in the PS script: "`"" + $($args[0] -replace "\\n","`n") + "`"" and this in the .bat file: "Line1\nLine2" results in a message that looks like this: "Line1Line2" except that the  Line2" is on a lower line.